# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.DocumentHelper

Tags: apache-poi, java-11

Getting the below exception while trying to call the XSSFWorkbook.close() method.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.DocumentHelper
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.save(ContentTypeManager.java:428)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:518)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1489)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.close(OPCPackage.java:452)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.close(POIXMLDocument.java:204)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.close(XSSFWorkbook.java:590)
```

Below are the maven dependencies :-

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

Tried adding an extra direct xerces dependency also to pom, but that too didnt resolve the exception.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Any suggestions to resolve it?

Comment: the versions of poi and poi-ooxml need to be the same

Comment: @PJFanning Updated both to  <version>4.1.2</version>, but still getting the same exception

Comment: `org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.DocumentHelper` is part of `poi-ooxml`, which is in your dependencies list. Did you clean your project of any older `poi` jars?

Comment: @slindenau : No. Also, the workbook.save() works for us, but its the workbook.close() method which throws error and traces to ContentTypeManager which has a reference to DocumentHelper which doesn't get resolved.

Comment: If you have multiple versions of this jar on your classpath, it might load an older one that didn't have this new class yet. So please check if clean/rebuild helps?